# keep getting an error with this code

Tags: java, palindrome

how do i make the else statement input whether the numbers that i entered are palindrome or not? the first part works nad im just stuck in the else statement trying to figure out how to make it work. heres my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Lab6
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
      String pal1, pal2="";
      int choice;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


      System.out.println("Word(w) or Number(n)?");
      choice = in.nextLine().charAt(0);

      if (choice == 'w') {

          System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
          pal1= in.nextLine();

          int length = pal1.length();


          for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            pal2 = pal2 + pal1.charAt(i);


         if (pal1.equals(pal2))
            System.out.println("The word you entered is a palindrome.");
         else
            System.out.println("The word you entered is not a palindrome.");
        }
      else{

          System.out.println("Enter a bunch of numbers: ");
          pal1 = in.nextLine();

          pal1 = String.valueOf(in.nextInt());
          int numLength = pal1.length();

          for ( int j = numLength - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
            pal2 = pal2 + pal1.charAt(j);

         if (pal1.equals(pal2))
            System.out.println("The numbers you entered is a palindrome.");
         else
            System.out.println("The numbers you entered is not a palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: What "first part"?  Which `else` statement?  (There are three of them.)  You need to be more specific about what problem you're trying to resolve.

Comment: the first if else statement. not the if else statement inside the if else statement. @Wyzard

Comment: its not outputting whether the numbers are palindrome or not @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Alternatively, take out a pen and paper and write out your code's execution. Add more log statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very ambiguous, if you are trying to tell the user that the string entered is NOT a palindrome, then see bellow...

Have you tried putting the if statement in brackets? you have to careful when writing if/for statement without them.

```
public class Lab6
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
      String pal1, pal2="";
      int choice;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


      System.out.println("Word(w) or Number(n)?");
      choice = in.nextLine().charAt(0);

      if (choice == 'w') {

          System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
          pal1= in.nextLine();

          int length = pal1.length();


          for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            pal2 = pal2 + pal1.charAt(i);


         if (pal1.equals(pal2)){
            System.out.println("The word you entered is a palindrome.");
         } else{
            System.out.println("The word you entered is not a palindrome.");
         }
        }
      else{

          System.out.println("Enter a bunch of numbers: ");
          pal1 = in.nextLine();

          pal1 = String.valueOf(in.nextInt());
          int numLength = pal1.length();

          for ( int j = numLength - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
            pal2 = pal2 + pal1.charAt(j);

         if (pal1.equals(pal2))
            System.out.println("The numbers you entered is a palindrome.");
         else
            System.out.println("The numbers you entered is not a palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck with your lab ;)

Also something like this might be more efficient:

```
boolean isPal(String input) {
    // go through half the string length
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() / 2; i++) {
        // match first half to second half (regardless if odd or even) 
        // -1 because strings starta at a 0 index
        if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```